# How to correctly ask a bartender for a drink in Madrid?

Tags: traducción, españa, español-neutral, cortesía, ustedeo

I've seen various versions but not sure what would be an acceptable polite phrase. In Mexico a bartender told me it's "ME DAS un mojito, por favor", in Barcelona a waitress told me I can just say "QUIERO un vino, por favor". Both seem a little too demanding and not polite translated to English so I'm not sure I should be using them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are, of course, many ways to ask for a drink, and most of them will have the same basic result: You receiving a drink.

As you imply, some are more polite than others.

If the bartender has already asked you "¿Qué te gustaría tomar?" (or similar), you can politely respond pretty much as you suggested:

> Quiero un vino, por favor.

If you have to approach the bartender/server, then you may want to be a bit more polite.

> Disculpa / Perdona. ¿Me traes un vino, por favor?

Or as my wife (who lived in Madrid for 10 years) says would be far more common:

> Perdona. ¿Me traes un vinito?

The diminuitive on 'vino' adds some 'kid gloves' to the statement, making it a bit more polite.

She also points out that in Madrid it's uncommon to use *usted* except when addressing your superior (in age or position), so wait staff would generally not be addressed with *usted*.

Comment: You can also say `¿Me pones un vino?`

Comment: A barman once got angry at me in Spain because I did not address him as *usted*, but this is indeed quite unusual. You would use *usted*, nevertheless, at a smart restaurant, and it is always fine to use *usted* with someone who has previously addressed you as *usted*.

Comment: "Traer" makes more sense for a waiter, I think, who is bringing something to you at a table.  If you're sitting at a bar, then "traer" doesn't work so well. // I think what the OP was asking about mainly was the tone, though.  This can vary so much, depending on country, region, ages of the relevant people, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The polite (and I think most common) way is "¿Me pone X, por favor?" being X "un vino", "una coca-cola", "una tapa de jamón". As Flimzy said, if you have to approach the bartender, add "Perdone" before

Comment: _Un vino, por favor_ is the most common expression in Madrid. _Por favor_ is enough to be polite. If you like to specify a verb, use _poner_ better than _traer_: *¿Me pones un vino, por favor? / Ponme un vino, por favor*